# Auto load and unload element

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below snippet will load an element on page load using jquery,css, and javascript.

```js
$('.callqueue').click(function(){
  $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open');
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});


$(window).load(function (){
  $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

```css
#man {
    display:none;
}

#dddnav {
    height:30%;
    background:#333;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:-270px;
    width:300px;
    transition:right .5s;
    -webkit-transition:right .5s;
}

#dddnav.menu-open {
    right:0;
    transition:right .5s;
    -webkit-transition:right .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="callqueue"> CLICK </button>
    
<div id="dddnav" style="background: red; top: 10%;">
<img id="man" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

However, I want the element to load after 3 seconds after the page load, and to unload it after 5 seconds without having to click on the button. How can I get this done using javascript? I found this link:  https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/toggle-classes-with-delays/ but i cant seems to make it work.

Would appreciate any response, example. Thank you!

Comment: Try `SetTimeout` function

Comment: How can I get this done on the snippet above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing

```js
$('.callqueue').click(function(){
  $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open');
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});

// Let's define a callable to be used inside setTimeout.
toggleIt = function(){
    $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open')
};
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            toggleIt()
            setTimeout(toggleIt, 2000) // 5s as 3 + 2         
        }, 3000
    )
})
```

```css
#man {
    display:none;
}

#dddnav {
    height:30%;
    background:#333;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:-270px;
    width:300px;
    transition:right .5s;
    -webkit-transition:right .5s;
}

#dddnav.menu-open {
    right:0;
    transition:right .5s;
    -webkit-transition:right .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="callqueue"> CLICK </button>
    
<div id="dddnav" style="background: red; top: 10%;">
<img id="man" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: @RenzC.Gohing Any question?

Answer (score 2):

## `async` and `await`

To avoid race conditions and ensure that each call to functions go in proper order (although order isn't that important with a method like `toggleClass()`), use [**`async`** and **`await`**](https://javascript.info/async-await) keywords with **[`setTimeout()`](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)**.

---

### Demo

```js
$(window).load(openClose);

$('.callqueue').click(slideNav);

async function openClose() {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  var open = await slideNav();
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  var close = await slideNav();
};

function slideNav() {
  $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open');
}
```

```css
#man {
  display: none;
}

#dddnav {
  height: 30%;
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -270px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: right .5s;
  -webkit-transition: right .5s;
}

#dddnav.menu-open {
  right: 0;
  transition: right .5s;
  -webkit-transition: right .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="callqueue"> CLICK </button>

<div id="dddnav" style="background: red; top: 10%;">
  <img id="man" src="https://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted to happen. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function (){
  var start_time = new Date().getTime();
  while (true) {
   if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 3000){ 
     $('#dddnav').toggleClass('menu-open');
     break;
   }
  }
});
```